# react native gesture handler failed build

Tags: android, react-native, npm, react-navigation

as I explained in a previous question, I'm new in the React-Native world.
I'm developing an app just to prove my skills and everything seems to be good, but today I tried to deal with react-navigation.
So I followed the various steps (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html) :

1. React-navigation installation : `npm install --save react-navigation`
2. Gesture handler installation: `npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler`
3. Modifications of `MainActivity.java`.

Anyway, when I try to install the app with the comand `react-native run-android`
I get this error:
[image]

P.S. I've already had a problem with react-navigation before, so I decided to follow many suggestion posted by people having here in StackOverflow and I try to unistall and re-install react-navigation, then to link modules...etc. But I think I made things worse.
 **React version is 0.60.**
Solutions ? Thank you in advance

Comment: which react native version you are using?

Comment: This problem occurs when you are using the react native version 6.0

Comment: There is already a ticket related to this on the github https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6068

Comment: I use version 0.60

Answer (score 0):

I've made it work in my project, you can use these command to make it run, then wait for a release from the mainteners:

```
1) npm install --save-dev jetifier
2) npx jetify
3) npx react-native run-android
4) npx jetify
```

Note that this is a workaround until they update the lib.